# C Trying to validate integer

Tags: c, validation, integer, infinite-loop

Trying to validate integer but when wrong value type entered an infinite loop of first printf appears.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int input;
do{
    int starCount;
    printf("Please enter a number:");
    scanf("%d",input);
    do{
        scanf("%d",&input);
    }while(isdigit(input));
    for(starCount=0; starCount<input; starCount++){
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");       
}while(input>0);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: I suggest reading some [documentation for the function scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) and then mentally simulating the execution of your code to see why it doesn't work.

Comment: 1) Why is there a call to `scanf()` before the loop? 2) You should be checking the value returned by the call to `scanf()`.

Comment: That you have two `scanf` calls is suspect. That the first of them is not passing it's variable by address invokes *undefined behavior*. I'd start with those.

Comment: @Andrei Pak: Why are you trying to apply `isdigit` to  your `input` and what did you expect it to do? Please, explain your thinking behind this application of `isdigit`. How did you come up with the idea?

Comment: isdigit checks if a character is a digit, it is meaningless to apply it to an int filled out by scanf - scanf will have called isdigit while processing the input string

Comment: Start by fixing the compilation warnings.  The most important (from compiling with `gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra`) are *incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function `printf`*, *incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function `scanf`* and *format `%d` expects argument of type `int *`, but argument 2 has type `int`*.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong for two reasons:

- You checked `input` at the end of `do..while`, but used it previously in `for` loop.
- There is absolutely no need to use double `do..while` loop.

There is another error with your initial `scanf` as well:

```
scanf("%d", input);  // <-- should be `&input`
```

---

For what you need, a single `do..while` would be suffice:

```
    int input;
    do{
        int starCount;
        printf("Please enter a number:");
        if( 1 != scanf("%d",&input) || input < 0 )   // <-- check return value of scanf and valid `input`
        {
            break;
        }
        for(starCount=0; starCount<input; starCount++){
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");       
    }while(1);
```

Notice that you can/should use the return value of `scanf` and check if `input` is valid before the `for` loop.